# JavaScript - Binary search hangs every time

Tags: javascript, arrays, binary-search

I have a 2D array, something like the following:

```
[1.11, 23]
[2.22, 52]
[3.33, 61]
...
```

Where the array is ordered by the first value in each row.

I am trying to find a value within the array that is *close* to the search value - within a certain sensitivity. The way this is set up, and the value of the sensitivity, ensure only one possible match within the array.

The search value is the current x-pos of the mouse. The search is called on `mousemove`, and so is being called often.

Originally I had the following (using a start-to-end `for` loop):

```
for(var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    if(Math.abs(arr[i][0] - x) <= sensitivity){
        hit = true;
        break;
    }
}
```

And it works like a charm. So far, I've only been using small data sets, so there is no apparent lag using this method. But, eventually I will be using much larger data sets, and so want to switch this to a *Binary Search*:

```
var a = 0;
var b = arr.length - 1;
var c = 0;

while(a < b){
    c = Math.floor((a + b) / 2);

    if(Math.abs(arr[c][0] - x) <= sensitivity){
        hit = true;
        break;
    }else if(arr[c][0] < x){
        a = c;
    }else{
        b = c;
    }
}
```

This works well, for all of 2 seconds, and then it hangs to the point where I need to restart my browser. I've used binary searches plenty in the past, and cannot for the life of me figure out why this one isn't working properly.

**EDIT 1**

```
var sensitivity = (width / arr.length) / 2.001
```

The points in the array are equidistant, and so this sensitivity ensures that there is no ambiguous 1/2-way point in between two `arr` values. You are either in one or the other.

Values are created dynamically at page load, but look exactly like what I've mentioned above. The x-values have more significant figures, and the y values are all over the place, but there is no significant difference between the small sample I provided and the generated one.

**EDIT 2**

Printed a list that was dynamically created:

```
[111.19999999999999, 358.8733333333333]
[131.4181818181818, 408.01333333333326]
[151.63636363636363, 249.25333333333327]
[171.85454545454544, 261.01333333333326]
[192.07272727272726, 298.39333333333326]
[212.29090909090908, 254.2933333333333]
[232.5090909090909, 308.47333333333324]
[252.72727272727272, 331.1533333333333]
[272.94545454545454, 386.1733333333333]
[293.16363636363633, 384.9133333333333]
[313.3818181818182, 224.05333333333328]
[333.6, 284.53333333333325]
[353.81818181818187, 278.2333333333333]
[374.0363636363637, 391.63333333333327]
[394.25454545454556, 322.33333333333326]
[414.4727272727274, 300.9133333333333]
[434.69090909090926, 452.95333333333326]
[454.9090909090911, 327.7933333333333]
[475.12727272727295, 394.9933333333332]
[495.3454545454548, 451.27333333333326]
[515.5636363636366, 350.89333333333326]
[535.7818181818185, 308.47333333333324]
[556.0000000000003, 395.83333333333326]
[576.2181818181822, 341.23333333333323]
[596.436363636364, 371.47333333333324]
[616.6545454545459, 436.9933333333333]
[636.8727272727277, 280.7533333333333]
[657.0909090909096, 395.4133333333333]
[677.3090909090914, 433.21333333333325]
[697.5272727272733, 355.09333333333325]
[717.7454545454551, 333.2533333333333]
[737.963636363637, 255.55333333333328]
[758.1818181818188, 204.7333333333333]
[778.4000000000007, 199.69333333333327]
[798.6181818181825, 202.63333333333327]
[818.8363636363644, 253.87333333333328]
[839.0545454545462, 410.5333333333333]
[859.272727272728, 345.85333333333324]
[879.4909090909099, 305.11333333333323]
[899.7090909090917, 337.8733333333333]
[919.9272727272736, 351.3133333333333]
[940.1454545454554, 324.01333333333326]
[960.3636363636373, 331.57333333333327]
[980.5818181818191, 447.4933333333333]
[1000.800000000001, 432.3733333333333]
```

As you can see, it is ordered by the first value in each row, ascending.

**SOLUTION**

Changing the condition to

```
while(a < b)
```

and

```
var b = positions.length;
```

and

```
else if(arr[c][0] < x){
    a = c + 1;
}
```

did the trick.

Comment: Think of what all can cause that while loop to never end..

Comment: perhaps you need to show a minimal array that causes the problem, along with what `x` and `sensitivity` are

Comment: Does the array have an odd or even number of elements? And can x be larger than the highest array value?

Comment: @nnnnnn The array can have either odd or even contents number of elements. And x cannot be larger than the highest value.

Comment: OK. So your array is generated based on the screen resolution or browser width? (Azoundria's answer explains in full what I was hinting at.)

Comment: Sure, we'll say that. Based on a div-width, based on window percentage, based on resolution. Solved it, shown in the original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your binary search seems to be a bit off: try this.

```
var arr = [[1,0],[3,0],[5,0]];

var lo = 0;
var hi = arr.length;

var x = 5;
var sensitivity = 0.1;

while (lo < hi) {
    var c = Math.floor((lo + hi) / 2);
    if (Math.abs(arr[c][0] - x) <= sensitivity) {
        hit = true;
        console.log("FOUND " + c);
        break;
    } else if (x > arr[c][0]) {
        lo = c + 1;
    } else {
        hi = c;
    }
}
```

---

This is meant as a general reference to anyone implementing binary search.

Let:

- `lo` be the smallest index that may possibly contain your value,
- `hi` be *one more* than the largest index that may contain your value

If these conventions are followed, then binary search is simply:

```
while (lo < hi) {
    var mid = (lo + hi) / 2;

    if (query == ary[mid]) {
        // do stuff

    else if (query < ary[mid]) {

        // query is smaller than mid
        // so query can be anywhere between lo and (mid - 1)
        // the upper bound should be adjusted

        hi = mid;
     else {

        // query can be anywhere between (mid + 1) and hi.
        // adjust the lower bound

        lo = mid + 1;
}
```

Comment: It isn't quite that simple. Please see the edited question for a sample of the array. The sensitivity is half the difference between any two points (x-values). Like I said, it does work, for a couple points, and then locks up.

Comment: @Birrel alright I see your edit, but it seems you haven’t provided a sample value of x?

Comment: x is the x-coordinate of the mouse. Pick a number. That's your x. It will be a whole number, somewhere within the range of the values in the array.

Comment: @Birrel my code seems to be working with your large dataset. Please try it.

Comment: Yeah, I'm not sure what's going on, but it's working now with your solution. At least with the modifications mentioned in the original question.

Comment: @Birrel your original implementation of binary search was wrong. Use this, it’s correct.

Comment: It's the `lo = c + 1;` that made the difference.

Comment: @Birrel check out my edit, hopefully you’ll remember binary search next time :)

Answer (score 2):

I don't know your exact situation, but here's a way the code could crash:

1) Start with an array with two X values. This array will have a length of 2, so a = 0, b = 1, c = 0.

2) a < b, so the while loop executes.

3) c = floor((a + b) / 2) = floor(0.5) = 0.

4) Assume the mouse is not within sensitivity of the first X value, so the first if branch does not hit.

5) Assume our X values are to the right of our mouse, so the second if branch enters. This sets a = c, or 0, which it already is.

6) Thus, we get an endless loop.